# Reading image and print out

Tags: python, ocr

im new to python so im trying to program a suduko solver so i can learn python on the way to finish the program.
The main idea is that, import a picture, let the program read it, and solve the suduko, then print out the answer. I have seen similar things everwhere but i cant make the program read the image and understand where everything is, tryed pyterresact but i get lots of error

```
from PIL import Image

import pytesseract

im = Image.open("sudukopic.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

And this is the error message i get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Emre/Desktop/Suduko solver/Sudukosolver.py", line 6, 
 in <module>
 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
 File "C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
 packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 193, in image_to_string
 return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
 File "C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
 packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
 run_tesseract(**kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
 packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 111, in run_tesseract
 proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 File "C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py",
 line 707, in __init__restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
 startupinfo)
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Det går inte att hitta filen
```

Comment: Specify full path.

Comment: Please read [How To Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your code using the {} button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant but from my perspective looks like you are looking at implementing a image recognition program.

I found [this](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/) resource that is very useful for beginner in CNN.

And for loading images, I recommend using `imread` from `skimage`.